# MySQL PHP jQuery - Row doesn't update?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am writing a CMS and I'm stuck at updating existing products in the products table....

The problem is that every value will receive the update besides the "text" and "stock" row... they go blank....

This is my code

Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="title">Product:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter new title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="price">Price:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Enter new price">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="stock">Stock:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" placeholder="Enter new stock">
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="text">Text:</label>
                    <textarea class='form-control' rows='5' id='newPostText' name='text' placeholder='Enter new text'></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Enter new description">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="brand">Brand:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand" placeholder="Enter new brand">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3"  for="keywords">Keywords:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="Enter new keywords">
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="updateProductRecord" pid="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>"><button type="submit" id="submitUpdateProduct" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></a>
            </form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").delegate("#updateProductRecord","click",function(event){
event.preventDefault();

var product_id = $(this).attr('pid');
updateProductRecord(product_id);

animatedLoading();
});

function updateProductRecord(product){

var title = $("#title").val();
var text = $("#text").val();
var summary = $("#description").val();
var keywords = $("#keywords").val();
var price = $("#price").val();
var stock = $("#stock").val();
var brand = $("#brand").val();

var product = product;

$.ajax({
    url :   "action.php",
    method: "POST",
    data    :   {updateProductRecord:1,pid:product,title:title,text:text,summary:summary,keywords:keywords,price:price,stock:stock,brand:brand},
    success :   function(data){
        $(".row").append(data);
    },
});

}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['updateProductRecord'])) {

$product_id = $_POST['pid'];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$category = $_POST["brand"];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$summary = $_POST['summary'];
$keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$stock = $_POST['stock'];
$date=date('d.m.y h:i:s');


$sql = "UPDATE products SET `title`='$title', `desc`='$summary', `price`='$price', `brand`='$category', `keywords`='$keywords', `stock`='$stock', `text`='$text' WHERE id='$product_id'";

$run_query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
if($run_query){

    echo "
        <div class='alert alert-success'>
            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
            <b>Your post has been submitted.!</b>
        </div>
        ";
}
else {

    echo "
        <div class='alert alert-warning'>
            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
            <b>Oops, something went wrong..</b>
        </div>
        ";
}

}
```

Comment: Just FYI `delegate()` was deprecated a *long* time ago. You should use `on()` instead. I would also suggest you update your version of jQuery to 1.12` at the very least

Comment: Have you tried loggong the errors you are getting while updation?

Comment: Check the `$_POST` values in your PHP file. Are they all present?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I use delegate because my on() didn't work on some content served by AJAX.. I was recommended by someone on here to use delegate instead in that case.

Comment: @Rahul I am not getting any errors, some values just aren't passed trough.

Comment: @RST My PHP code is above, so yes.

Comment: Use `$(document).on('click', "#updateProductRecord", function(event) ...`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, will use!

Comment: What I meant was, did you check the values of those variables. If something has gone wrong they could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

> Change the Jquery Text Field Value

```
var text = $("#newPostText").val();
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, didn't notice but this is not the problem.. The stock variable isn't getting trough aswell.